# Recompile elixir module with erlang OTP 25 when mix won't start

Tags: erlang, elixir, chocolatey

Whenever I use "mix deps.clean", "mix deps.get" or any mix command really, I get the following error :

```
15:18:28.936 [error] beam\beam_load.c(86): Error loading module 'Elixir.Code.Formatter':
  lambda already defined for label 747. To fix this, please recompile this module with an OTP 25 compiler.

15:18:28.936 [error] Loading of c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/Elixir/lib/elixir/ebin/Elixir.Code.Formatter.beam failed: :badfile

** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Code.Formatter.locals_without_parens/0 is undefined (module Code.Formatter is not available)
    (elixir 1.13.3) Code.Formatter.locals_without_parens()
    (elixir 1.13.3) lib/code/normalizer.ex:22: Code.Normalizer.normalize/2
    (elixir 1.13.3) lib/code.ex:1107: Code.quoted_to_algebra/2
```

I'v tried updating, removing and reinstalling both erlang and elixir with chocolatey, with no effect. How can I recompile the elixir module as is required please?

Thank you !

Comment: If you have recently updated your version of Elixir or Erlang, make sure you clear out the old compiled files.  E.g. `rm -rf _build` and sometimes `rm -rf deps` just to make sure.  The runtime can tell if a file has been compiled or if it has been changed, but it doesn't always realize that it was compiled with a certain version.

Comment: sorry but both commands are unknown. Are they linux commands ? I also have elixir installed on wsl, which might be part of the problem, but this specific error I get on windows

Comment: Delete the `_build` and `deps` directories entirely so the app re-compiles.  That is what your error is telling you: "recompile this module".  The best way to force everything to re-compile is to delete the compiled files and re-compile.

Comment: I deleted both folders but I get the same error as previously when I run mix deps.get

Comment: From my understanding, it's not a dependancy of the project that causes the problem but the standard elixir libraries : the problematic file is in c:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/Elixir/lib/elixir/ebin/, so deleting _build and deps in my project folder shouldn't allow to recompile it. What I ended up doing is reinstalling everything from wsl and working on ubuntu from now on. It didn't solve my windows issue, but now I can work. Thank you a lot for helping me

Comment: How did you install Erland and Elixir? Was it ASDF?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with elixir downgrade. The solution for me was too delete the folder "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\mix". OS is Windows 10